# Test Android Wear apps on phone?

Tags: android, wear-os

Interestingly enough, I noticed that when developing, I can choose to run a Wear app on the phone instead of a Wear device. It looks the same--just huge, of course.

Based on https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/QhWQArNDfS3, I gather I could use ADB to make the phone screen small enough to do a fair imitation of a rectangular smartwatch...

But what about testing for round Android Wear devices? Is there something I can do to the phone (or a rectangular Android Wear device, for that matter) to make it show as a circle (and even better, identify as a round device to Android Wear) in order to test the round interfaces?

Yes, there's always cutting a round hole out of a page and holding that over the device, but that's obviously far from ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test your app on a round emulator. Here are instructions how to do this: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

EDIT:
About round and forcing round on a square device: you can try to pretend that the device is round, but it's a little hacky and ugly.

In your `Activity` you need to implement inset listener and then use reflection to change `WindowInsets.mRound` field. Then dispatch the insets further down the hierarchy. This will trick your views to think that the device is round.

Check this article about handling square and round: http://gruszczy.blogspot.com/2015/03/handling-round-screens-using.html It describes how insets with the information about device display type are delivered.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, there's always the emulator--with all the failings of the Android emulator... bugginess and mind-numbing slowness. That's why I was asking about how to test it on physical devices.

Comment: Check out my edit, it describes how to fake insets with isRound() information.